# Errors related to output initialization is produced when using decoupled IO

Tags: chisel

When I use DecoupledIO, it seems that it generates errors caused by **Reference io is not fully initialized**.

This is because I have to initialize Output, in this case, bits, and valid or ready(depending on flipped or not)

Let's assume that bits and valid is Output.

when I use following statement:

```
when(reset.toBool) {
  bits := 0.U
  valid := true.B
}
```

it generates error.

But when the initialize statement exist outside of when statement, it does not produce errors.

So, how to solve such initialization problems?

Do I always have to initialize such values outside of when statement although I want to put it inside *when(reset.toBool)* statement?

Even, the router example in the wiki page produces error even though I follow the guide described by unconnected wire section(this was due to the fact that all init statement exist inside when statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question but a little hard to explain.  When you wrap the output initialization in the `when(io.reset)` it creates a edge case where the wire may not be initialized if reset is not been asserted.  The easiest fix is to do both

```
bits := 0.U
valid := true.B
when(reset.toBool) {
  bits := 0.U
  valid := true.B
}
```

Last connect semantics will ensure that the reset and decoupled behavior is take precedence but that you will have covered the edge case. The chisel team is aware of this problem and looking for a more elegant situation. See [Chisel Issue 703](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues/703)